# Is it possible to use the bunyan cli formatter to process logback logs?

Tags: json, logback, bunyan

My logback logs from a Java app are generated in json format. The node service is generating json logs via bunyan. Is it possible to use the buynan cli on the logback log stream to make the those logs human readable like the cli can for the node buynan logs? or is there a similar cli to use for logback output reformatting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your configure your logback formatter to output in the format that bunyan expects, then yes this should work.  It's a good idea in fact.